# Add values from a column

Tags: sql, datatable, count, sum, plpgsql

How can I sum the values of a column in a table whose data is of type `text`. I tried with the following code and it gives me the following error:

```
SELECT sum(periodo::INTEGER) as period
FROM informe_reposo
```

> Error: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer

Comment: Please translate your error message to English.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
SELECT sum(periodo::INTEGER) as period
FROM informe_reposo
```

assumes that `periodo` can be converted to an integer with no problems.  Unfortunately, Postgres does not have a safe convert, but you can use `case` and come close:

```
SELECT sum(case when periodo ~ '^[-]?[0-9]{1,9}$' then periodo end)::INTEGER) as period
FROM informe_reposo;
```

I would advise you to look that the values that fail -- to see what you should do about them.